# CloudWatch Logs limit 1 query doesn't stop after finding 1 result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

basically I have a query such as:

```
fields @timestamp, @message | filter @message =~ /some_regex_expr/ | limit 1
```

And the regex is quite complex so it takes some time when matching. I would be satisfied with just 1 match, but I have noticed that once it's found and displayed already, the query just keeps going until it goes through all logs.

This behaviour is a bit weird and it almost looks like the limit keyword is only applied at post-processing (which determines which results actually get shown to the user, after ALL of them had been found already). Is there something I can do to make it truly stop after the first match?